# No notifications for followed posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, follow-post

For the past several hours I have not been receiving any notifications about posts I have followed.  The timestamp for the last followed post notification I received was 2021-07-06 16:23:20Z, and in the 9 hours since then I have seen several comments and answers on posts I followed for which I did not receive notifications.   I appear to be receiving other notifications as usual (specifically, I have received notifications for comments on my posts and comments replying to my comments).

Update: This seems to be fixed now.  I have been receiving followed post notifications as of 2021-07-07 09:33:56Z, and others also report receiving them recently in the comments below.

Comment: Repro'ed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also reproduced. Followed a post and there was a comment. I did not get a notification. [I find this inconvenient](https://i.imgur.com/JArtyjG.png)

Comment: Went through some of my followed posts. I can confirm that neither edits nor answers have triggered a notification.

Comment: I just received a notification as [“followed question — comment”](//i.stack.imgur.com/vPR9C.png) for the last comment, but not the other missing notifications for other network activity in the interim.

Comment: I received a note from @SebastianSimon's comment, so no repro here.  Unless it's been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @Ollie Yours was the first “followed post” notification I received since 2021-07-06 13:28:27 UTC, and I can confirm as well that several followed posts did produce activity which did not result in a notification.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apologies, a bad "fix" made its way out to production that itself caused another issue... And the tests passed because they had a bug that made it impossible to reproduce that issue because of the way they handled a background process.

Yes, this was my fault and I apologise, but I promise I've now fixed the tests *and* the code and that it won't happen again. Maybe

Comment: But did you write a test for the tests?  

Comment: @ColleenV [Quis test ipsos tests?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F)

Comment: @VLAZ That was my first thought, but I couldn’t remember the Latin.

Comment: I like the open ending here! Keeps us vigilant :)